# Set reference in Go

Tags: go, pass-by-reference

How to pass an interface by reference and let the method fill it for me? Something like  this:

```
var i CustomInterface
Get("title" , ref i)
i.SomeOperationWithoutTypeAssertion() //i is nil here(my problem)

func Get(title string, iRef ref interface{}){
     iRef = new(ATypeWhichImplementsTheUnderlyingInterface)
}
```

I want `i` not to be nil after calling the `Get` method. How to pass `i` as reference to the `Get` method?

Comment: @ OneOfOne: I want to pass the interface as reference and let the method initialize it.

Comment: please give an advice instead of voting down, I need to pass an interface by reference and let the method fill it by an instance of a type which implements the passed interface.

Answer (score 3):

Go doesn't have the concept of transparent reference arguments as found in languages like C++, so what you are asking is not possible:  Your `Get` function receives a copy of the interface variable, so won't be updating variable in the calling scope.

If you do want a function to be able to update something passed as an argument, then it must be passed as a pointer (i.e. called as `Get("title", &i)`).  There is no syntax to specify that an argument should be a pointer to an arbitrary type, but all pointers can be stored in an `interface{}` so that type can be used for the argument.  You can then use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) / [switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) or the [`reflect` package](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) to determine what sort of type you've been given.  You'll need to rely on a runtime error or panic to catch bad types for the argument.

For example:

```
func Get(title string, out interface{}) {
    ...
    switch p := out.(type) {
    case *int:
        *p = 42
    case *string:
        *p = "Hello world"
    ...
    default:
        panic("Unexpected type")
    }
}
```